# List Transition using vue and bootstrap: prevent deleted item from moving up

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

Using vue.js and bootstrap, trying to implement a transition group where items
fade away and the remaining items move into place, I encounter that the fading item simultaniously moves up to list position 0.

I get this bevahiour only if I use a vue transition-group together with a bootstrap list-group.

Using a plain transition-group without list-group behaves as I intended.

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/exd7zdex/4/

#### js

```
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
    data: {
    items: [],
    counter: 0
  },
  methods: {
    addItem: function() {
        this.items.push("Item " + this.counter++);
    },
    removeItem: function () {
        if (this.items.length == 0) {
        return 
      } else {
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.items.length);
        this.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
  }
})

for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    app.addItem();
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="app" class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <button @click="addItem">add</button>
    <button @click="removeItem">remove</button>
  </div>
  <transition-group tag="ul" name="mylist" class="list-group">
    <li class="mylist-item list-group-item" v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
      {{ item }}
    </li>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

#### css

```
.mylist-item {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.mylist-enter, .mylist-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.mylist-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This is be cause you are using `position: absolute;` on leaving item. So the behaviour is expected.

Comment: If I do not use `position: absolute` the other items don't move but just pop into place after the animation is done.

Comment: And this does also not explain, why this happens only when using `list-group`

Comment: You don't have to use position: absolute, there are different props to animate also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered the css for `.mylist-leave-active` to handle `height` and `padding` instead of `position:absolute`.

Hope that this helps you move closer to what you are going after.

```
.mylist-leave-active {
  /* position: absolute; */
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  color: transparent;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/e7s90s4w/3/

Comment: Thx, yes this is a much closer. But I'm still wondering why the settings of the vue example work on an ordinary list but not on a list-group. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure. The only things Vue handles here is the adding and removal of the related classes. The rest is just CSS transition. If there's an issue, it's more likely that it's a CSS issue and not a Vue issue. Hope this helps.